# Alamofire Contextual type anyobject cannot be used with dictionary literal

Tags: swift, rest, alamofire, nsurl

I am invoking a POST request where I provide the params, url from another method and get the error:

```
Contextual type anyobject cannot be used with dictionary literal
```

This is how I invoke and get the error here:

```
API.sharedInstance.post(NSURL(string: baseURL)!, params: ["name":  val, "owner": "John"])
```

Here is my `Alamofire` code:

```
func post(url: NSURL, params: AnyObject) {

    Alamofire.request(.POST, baseURL, parameters: params as! [String : AnyObject])
        .validate()
        .responseJSON { response in
            switch response.result {
            case .Success:
                print("Validation Successful")
                print("response = \(response)")
            case .Failure(let error):
                print(error)
            }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to replace

```
func post(url: NSURL, params: AnyObject) {    
    Alamofire.request(.POST, baseURL, parameters: params as! [String : AnyObject])
```

with

```
func post(url: NSURL, params: [String : AnyObject]) {    
    Alamofire.request(.POST, baseURL, parameters: params)
```

Comment: thats what I had earlier but XCode recommended me [String: AnyObject] and that didnt work